# Porting .net Framework to .net core Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am porting a project from .net framework to .net core. For that I created a new .net core (2.2.0) and adding files. In the .net framework I have using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query library and I could not find it in .net core. I am new to .net framework and .net core the nearest I could find is in this post 
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/604

I want to know what would be the possible option to implement this in .netcore.

Comment: There is a .net core port available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/)

Comment: @Rex that is not a .net core library. It is part of the .net 4.* framework

Comment: I am new to .net what would be the best approach to solve this problem if i cant find the .net core library.